# Problem in Parsing the XML. With Numeric Tag

Tags: xml, parsing

The problem in Parsing below XML. If I replace Numeric Tag as alphanumeric, then it is working fine.

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ClaimReferenceBO>
   <skCodeMap>
       <AS>50027026</AS>
       <80>7028907</80>
   </skCodeMap>
   <versionListMap>
        <7028905>0</7028905>
   </versionListMap>
</ClaimReferenceBO>'
```

The Content Of Elements Must Consist Of Well-formed Character Data Or Markup., Line '1', Column '48'.
The Content Of Elements Must Consist Of Well-formed Character Data Or Markup.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML Tag names must not start with Numbers.

https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/07/25/namingparts.html